# Declaring a return value of enum containing a case with a generic type?

Tags: swift, enums

I have a simple networking result enum. If the call is successful, I'll return success with an object of the requested type. If it's unsuccessful, I'll return a failure message.

```
enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(String)
}

func testAPI(requestedObjClass: String) -> Result {...}
```

With this code, the compiler gives the error:

```
Reference to generic type 'Result' requires arguments in <...>
```

It wants me to define the type of the 'success' case with something like `Result<MyObj>`, but it could be different types depending on the argument, and I may not even return success at all. What's the correct architecture for this 'Result' idea?

Answer (score 2):

The compiler needs to resolve the generic type placeholders values at *compile time.* For example, in

```
if case .success(let res) = testAPI(requestedObjClass: "...") {
    print(res)
}
```

the compiler needs to known the type of `res`. Therefore you cannot
return a `Result` where the corresponding `T` is determined at runtime only.

A possible solution might be to pass the requested result type as
a type and not as a string, and make the function generic:

```
func testAPI<T>(requestedObjClass: T.Type) -> Result<T> {
    // ...
}
```

Then in a call like

```
if case .success(let res) = testAPI(requestedObjClass: Int.self) {
    print(res)
}
```

the compiler can infer the type `T` (and thus the type of the result
value `res`) at compile time, in this example as `Int`.

Comment: You might be able to get away with removing `requestedObjClass` entirely, but I'm not sure if the Swift compiler will be smart enough to infer the type from `if case.success(let res: Int) = testAPI() {`

Comment: @Samah: The type can be inferred from the context e.g. in `let res: Result<Int> = testAPI()`, but `if case success(let res as Int) = testAPI()` does not compile. I'd still prefer `let res = testAPI(Int.self)`.

Answer (score 1):

> It wants me to define the type of the 'success' case with something
>   like Result, but it could be different types depending on the
>   argument

You can write some protocol like `MyProtocol` and then extend `MyObj` and all other needed classes with this protocol e.g.

```
class MyObj { }

protocol MyProtocol { }

extension MyObj: MyProtocol { }

extension Int: MyProtocol { }

enum Result<T> {
    case success(T)
    case failure(String)
}

func testAPI(requestedObjClass: String) -> Result<MyProtocol> {
    return .failure("Not implemented")
}
```

And it will be good idea in general to form some constraints for `MyProtocol` like methods or computed variables. Having something too dynamic is not very Swiftic way.